# Qt5 custom QDialog without using qt creator

Tags: c++, qt5, raspbian

I am trying to write a custom pure C++ QDialog so that I can create a base class and inherit from it later. The follow is the code that shows a QLabel in a QDialog:

"EDLController.h"

```
#ifndef EDLController_h
#define EDLController_h

#include <QDialog>

class EDLController : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    EDLController(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};
#endif
```

"EDLController.cpp"

```
EDLController::EDLController(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    QVBoxLayout vBoxLayout;

    QLabel label("text");
    vBoxLayout.addWidget(&label);

    setLayout(&vBoxLayout);
    setWindowTitle("test");
}
```

"main.cpp"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    EDLController *w = new EDLController();
    w->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

However, it shows an empty window with correct title:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldrhg.png)

The program is running on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian). Can anyone help me to find out the problem.

Comment: `vBoxLayout` is local to the `EDLController` ctor and will be destructed as soon as it goes out of scope.  Make it a member of `EDLController`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your label declaration. You create a local variable label wich is destroyed at the end of the EDLController constructor.
You can confirm that by inheriting QLabel like this :

---

```
class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyLabel(const QString& str, QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QLabel(str,parent){}
    ~MyLabel() {qDebug() << "LABEL DELETED";}
};
```

---

The "LABEL DELETED" message will be logged when the QDialog is instanced. 
And, of course, you cannot display a deleted widget.

The correct code is the following :

---

```
 QLabel* label = new  QLabel("text");
 vBoxLayout.addWidget(label);
```

---

The label will be destoyed when the parent item (your dialog) will be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

`vBoxLayout` and `label` will be destroyed when `EDLController` constructor exits because they are local variables. Create new instances on heap to avoid that:

```
EDLController::EDLController(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout * vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QLabel * label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText("test");
    vBoxLayout->addWidget(label);

    setLayout(vBoxLayout);
    setWindowTitle("test");
}
```